# How to extract FASTA sequences in a file in which locus ID match with list in a csv file using python

Tags: python

csv file :

> 1.1,LOC_Os02g03440,Os02g0126700,osSmE-a,2,r,1399279,1401336,Sm 1,,
>   1.1,LOC_Os01g15310,Os01g0256900,osLSM4,1,r,8569841,8573555,Sm 1,,
>   1.1,LOC_Os07g07220,Os07g0166600,osSmB-a,7,f,3573405,3575954,Sm 1,,

fasta file :

> LOC_Os05g07030.3 pacid=33157318 polypeptide=LOC_Os05g07030.3
>   locus=LOC_Os05g07030 ID=LOC_Os05g07030.3.MSUv7.0 annot-version=v7.0
>   ATGCGAGCTCTCGCGGCGGCGGCGGCAACGGCAACAGCGACTGCAGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGCCTTCCCCCGCGCGCTTCCCTCTCCGCCTCGTCGTCACCCCGCGCGCCTCGTTAGGTCATTGTAGAGCATCTTCCTCCGCAAGGTCTCCGAGGAGG
>   LOC_Os05g04170.1 pacid=33157320 polypeptide=LOC_Os05g04170.1 locus=LOC_Os05g04170 ID=LOC_Os05g04170.1.MSUv7.0 annot-version=v7.0

output file should be like this:

> LOC_Os05g07030 ID=LOC_Os05g07030.1
>   ATGCGAGCTCTCGCGGCGGCGGCGGCAACGGCAACAGCGACTGCAGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGCCTTCCCCCGCGCGCTTCCCTCTCCGCCTCGTCGTCACCCCGCGCGCCTCGTTAGGTCATTGTAGAGCATCTTCCTCCGCAAGGTCTCCGAGGAGG

for example, if LOC_Os02g03440 id of csv file matches with locus of fasta file, I want to extract the sequence of that locus with its isoforms to another file. i'm very new to python and i wrote a script but i'm not getting the answer. please help me anyone to write to script for it.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import re
path=os.getcwd()
list_dir=os.listdir(path+'//Osativa')
if not os.path.exists('results'):
    os.makedirs('results')
fo1=open('./results/cdna.txt','w')
f1=open(path+'//2016-10-19 Rice SF List.csv').readlines()
f2=open(path+'//Osativa//'+'//Osativa_323_v7.0.cds.fa').readlines()
locus_id={}
for line in f1:
    locus_id=line.split(',')[1]
for line in f2:
    if line.startswith('>'):
        locus=line.split()[4]
        isoform=line.split()[0]
        CDS_length=0
        if locus_id==locus:
            fo1.write(locus_id+'\t'+locus+'\t'+str(CDS_length)+'\n')
        else:
            pass
    else:
        pass
fo1.close()
```

Comment: Please add the code you already have.

Comment: @ Klaus I already add my code. please comment on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it for instance:

```
import csv

locus_set = set()
fieldnames = ['Version', 'locus', 'ID', 'ID2', 'n', 'i', 'v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'x']
with open('test/FASTA_list.csv') as f:
    for row in csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=","):
        locus_set.add( row['locus'] )


with open('test/FASTA_results.txt', 'w') as fresult, \
     open('test/FASTA.fa') as f:

    while True:
        FASTA_1 = f.readline()
        FASTA_2 = f.readline()
        if not FASTA_1 or not FASTA_2: break

        FASTA = FASTA_1.split()
        locus = FASTA[3].split('=')[1]
        ID = FASTA[0]

        if locus in locus_set:
            fresult.write('%s\tID=%s\t%s\n' % (locus, ID, FASTA_2) )
```